# Play games services not working after upgrading to gms services 8.1

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-games, google-signin

I have an existing Android application (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.pixelprose.dice) that use play games services for years... I did not upgrade it since late june and leaderboards, login etc were working well...

Last week I tried to ugrade play services from 7.x to 8.1 and follow the steps described here to get a configuration file for analytics : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Since then, nobody can log in anymore in my app, using the published version and the under developpement version i get :

```
03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService: There is no linked app associated with this client ID.
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService: com.google.android.gms.games.server.error.GamesException
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.games.server.GamesServer.getResponseBlocking(GamesServer.java:164)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.getPlayerFromNetwork(PlayerAgent.java:1700)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.fetchPlayer(PlayerAgent.java:621)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.DataBroker.loadSelf(DataBroker.java:920)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$LoadSelfOperation.executeInternal(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:402)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$BaseOperation.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:51)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$OperationAdapter.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:487)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.chimera.BaseAsyncOperationService$OperationTask.run(BaseAsyncOperationService.java:179)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-03 13:25:18.815 9741-27255/? E/SignInIntentService:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-03 13:25:18.826 25900-25900/? E/LoadSelfFragment: Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

But :

- the app is still linked to the right project ID in the play developper console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish)
- the project still exists in cloud console https://console.developers.google.com/project
- the manifest reference the right app_id

How can I get rid of the missconfiguration introduced by setting up analytics here : https://developers.google.com/mobile/add ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For thoses wondering how to fix this you have to associate your application a second time in the play developper console... (as if you set up a new associated app : https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling)

So I have now two times the same app associated with a game service... both with the same app_id but not exactly :

- *{app_id}.apps.googleusercontent.com* old one not working anymore
- *{app_id}-{other_id}.apps.googleusercontent.com* new one that works fine

Comment: Can you clarify what the other_id is?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was struggling with this for the last two days. You just saved my sanity!

Comment: Jeez, even thinking it wouldn't work, I tried... and IT WORKED! Thanks a lot, man!